# How to skip CSS properties nested on a div

Tags: html, css

I have tried a lot of different ways but this is something that is bothering me very much. I want to apply CSS properties to a specific group the same elements nesting inside a div. So far the only way I have been able to that has been separating them with a new nesting inside like a div or a ul and them giving it an ID tag. I want to target only a few parts but I don't know how. It would be very happy if someone could tell me how to improve on this,

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
/* CSS for topbar*/

#topbar {
  display: block;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#topbar img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
#topbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* this removes bullet points in navbar*/
  margin: 0;
  /* this removes browser default margin*/
  padding: 0;
  /* this removes browser default padding*/
}
#topbar1 a {
  float: left;
}
#topbar2 li {
  float: right;
}
#topbar a {
  display: block;
}
#topbar1 a:link,
a:visited {
  width: 60px;
  /* this to set the width so that by default it doesnt go 100%*/
  text-decoration: none;
  /* removes the underline*/
  text-align: center;
  /* centers text*/
  color: black;
  font-weight: bolder;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px;
}
#topbar1 a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
/* This is the CSS for Search Bar */

#searchbar {
  border-style: none;
  background: url(../IMAGES/SEARCHBAR/bar1.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.Sbutton {
  border-style: none;
  background: url(../IMAGES/SEARCHBAR/button1.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 37px 37px;
  height: 37px;
  width: 37px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="IMAGES/Favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Main.css">
  <!--Page Style here-->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Cineflex</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id=topbar>
    <ul>
      <ul id='topbar1'>
        <li><a href="#">Log in</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id='topbar2'>
        <li>
          <div id="GoogleSearch">
            <form id="textbar" method="get" action="cgi-bin/search.cgi">
              <input type="text" id="searchbar" name="search" size="21" maxlength="120" placeholder="Search...">
              <input type="submit" value="" class="Sbutton">
            </form>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=en">
            <img class="twitterlogo" alt='twitterlogo.jpg' src="IMAGES/ICONS/Twitter.png"></img>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/">
            <img class="fblogo" alt='fblogo.jpg' src="IMAGES/ICONS/Facebook.ico"></img>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So far this is the way I have dealt with giving properties i seperated them with names like topbar 1 and topbar 2. but i am looking for a more efficient way to deal with this.

[Something like this but I want to center the text and i want the corner search to be inside the corner and i want all this content to have the same height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpfxj.png)

thank you for your time.

Comment: So... you want to be able to replace `#topbar1` and `#topbar2` with `#topbar > ul > ul` in your CSS? Because you can do that. [Here's a cheat-sheet for CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what question you're asking. How to avoid nested selectors? (Give the elements a class or id and style that.) How to avoid multiple ids? (You can use multiple levels in a CSS selector, but that can be problematic because of the increased specificity.) How to create a top bar like the linked image? (There are many ways to do that.) Can you perhaps narrow your post down to a very specific question.

Comment: yeah kind of like that but I want to also remove the ul i had nest inside and be able to apply some properties to the ones nested inside

Comment: I want it to look like these: 
<ul>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
</ul>                         but if i do this i cant select the last 2 li's and move to the left. and if select li averall it will also apply the same properties to the images nested inside. which i dont want to the same padding to or margin in all the li's nested inside only specific ones.

Comment: maybe use inline styles on the last 2 li's which would override any stylesheet styles